# Why does my array say write access violation partially through?

Tags: c++, arrays

Updated to be copy/pasted and run. My bad.

I know I'm probably going to get the whole "this question was asked already" but I spent sometime looking and couldn't find a matching problem. It's very possible I just don't know enough to look in the right place.

When I call InitSortedArray() it runs through a seemingly random number of elements before throwing exception: write access violation. Everytime I run it it stops at a different element number. Any ideas?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int * toSort;
const int SIZE = 100000;

void InitSortedArray()
{

    srand(0);
    toSort[0] = rand() % 5;
    cout << toSort[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
    {
        srand(0);
        toSort[i] = toSort[i - 1] + rand() % 5;
        cout << toSort[i] << endl;
    }
}

void Search()
{

    toSort[SIZE];

    InitSortedArray();
}

int main()
{
    Search();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Following @NathanOliver 's comment, try to provide a complete example, s.t. others can run your code. I suspect that you do not initialise the array correctly.

Comment: Updated it to be run. *Also the COUTs were there for me to better keep track of where it was dying. They're not necessary for the code.

Comment: You declare toSort as a pointer, but never allocate space for its content. Try using new[]

Comment: Again, `toSort[SIZE];` does nothing.

Comment: I swear C++ will be the death of me. Thanks for all the help. It was the new that was tripping me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int * toSort;
```

allocates a pointer to some data yet to be assigned to it. No data is ever assigned. You could

```
int * toSort = new int[100000];
```

but that picks up some memory management work you don't need. Any time you use `new[]` sooner or later you must `delete[]`. Instead use

```
const int SIZE = 100000; // place first so we can use it below
int toSort[SIZE];
```

or the more modern

```
const int SIZE = 100000; // place first so we can use it below
std::array<int, SIZE> toSort;
```

to declare an array.

```
toSort[100000];
```

in `Search` does nothing helpful (and is in fact harmful as it invokes [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) by accessing outside the bounds of `toSort`) and should be removed.

Extra stuff:

[`srand` reseeds and restarts the random number generator.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) It is only in truly rare circumstances that you want  to call it more than once, and in those cases there are many better options than `srand` and `rand`.

Place a single call to `srand` at the top of `main` and make absolutely certain you want `srand(0)` as this will always generate the exact same numbers on a given computer. It's great for testing, but not so good if you want a different sequence every time. Typical use is `srand(time(NULL))` to seed the generator based on the ever-changing flow of time. That's still not all that good, but good enough for most cases where `rand` is in use.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using an uninitialized pointer that points to random space, and trying to store elements and access elements in it.  Also, your inclusion of "array" doesn't make any sense here.  I believe what you want to do here is initialize your toSort array to actually point to a section of memory that you intend to point it to:

```
int toSort[SIZE];
```

instead of

```
int * toSort;
```

If you're looking to use the STL array (which is likely highly recommendable) then you need to explicitly use it:

```
std::array<int, SIZE> toSort;
```

The nice thing about using the STL is it takes care of a lot of the memory access issues you can run into like memory access violation.  Another helpful thing from the STL would be vector:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> toSort;
```

then later: (this adds an item to the back of the vector)

```
toSort.push_back(<some number>);
```

and to access:

```
int somethingElse = toSort[<index number>];
```

Arrays:   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Vectors:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector